# "Лицам старше 16 лет и более 70 кг" - тут логическое "и" или "или"?

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

> На детской площадке запрещается:
>
> - пользоваться детским оборудованием лицам старше 16 лет и более 70 кг
>
> ([Source](https://mega.ru/shops/7995/dybenko))

May I use the playground equipment if the above rule is to be interpreted formally as written? I am older than 16, but below 70 kG.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Semantically it's ambiguous, but logically if it was just a weight restriction why would they mention the age? So it seems to me to be 2 separate restrictions, although to avoid confusion it would be better phrased with или. Старше 16 лет или более 70кг.

Comment: >> *Semantically it's ambiguous* << Is it? They chose **и**, not **или**. And **и** means **and**. How is it ambiguous?

Comment: If we consider things from the logical standpoint, then it is unclear why they mention the age at all, in the first place. Playground equipment can get broken only by weight, not by age. I find it difficult to see how using the playground equipment by people over 16 can make harm if they are below the weight limit. The age is simply irrelevant if we are talking about the danger of breaking the equipment.

Comment: Yes, so the age limit is probably a separate limit that's there maybe so the adults don't occupy equipment that's meant for children? Having said that, it could also be that they don't want to discriminate against fat kids, but still want to limit the equipment to under 70kg if you're grown up. In which case it would mean that if you're both over 16 and 70кг you can't use it.

Comment: `They chose и, not или. And и means and. How is it ambiguous?` _"People who are older than 16 and over 70kg"_ can be interpreted as _"people who are over 16 and people who are over 70kg"_ or as _"people who are both over 16 and over 70kg"_

Comment: By the way, is it correct to say "лицам более 70 кг"? I feel my teacher might mark such a sentence as failed.

Comment: @Mitsuko it's not entirely correct, but it's a `канцеляризм` (clericalism), so it's kind of valid.

Comment: @Mitsuko Your teacher would mark half of the Russian segment of the internet as failed. As I mentioned many times the current situation with the quality of the Russian language in public sources is appalling. :)

Comment: It's not perfect, but it's one way to be tactful, almost euphemistic, a way to avoid bringing more attention to one's weight than necessary.

Comment: Do not be fooled, this example takes a logical AND

Answer (score 1):

This type of phrasing is somewhat common and may not make sense at the first glance if you interpret it like a conditional statement.

But if you translate it like this:

> Children’s equipment is forbidden to use to **both** those over 16 **and** those over 70 kg.

Then basically you subtract from the whole population two groups (which may intersect or not), leaving only those younger than 16 and weighing less than 70 kg.

Answer (score 1):

Это значит барьер: лицам, старше 16 лет запрещено играть на детских площадках и лицам, у которых вес больше 70 кг тоже. 
Это такая мера безопасности.
Подробнее здесь: https://gorod48.ru/news/1152851/